# TypeScript Coding Style Guide?

Tags: coding-style, typescript

I love the [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). Most of the rules also apply to TypeScript, but of course it doesn't cover specific TypeScript language features.

I have also found the [Microsoft TypeScript Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines) but they are for the TypeScript project itself, not for projects that **use** TypeScript.

Finally I found the [TypeScript Style Guide by Platypi](https://github.com/Platypi/style_typescript) but it's not as detailed as I'd like it to be. Is there another (official?) TypeScript Style Guide that I missed? Or are the two I listed the only ones that exist?

Comment: In my opinion, since the TypeScript compiler is programmed in TypeScript I think it's a good guide to follow (though it's quite bare)

Comment: @DavidSherret I agree that it contains a few good rules to follow, but it's rather specific to the TS compiler project and it's lacking a lot of the guidelines found in the Airbnb guide, like when to use `var` vs `let` etc.

Comment: Yeah that'd be great, so thanks for volunteering Johannes, I look forward to seeing the new guide  :)

Comment: @mallison I was asking for that comment ;-)

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug ... I can't find the exact tweet, but John Papa recently said on Twitter that he was working on one.  If its anything like the AngularJS style guide, then it will likely be *the* defacto guide.  

**Edit**: https://twitter.com/John_Papa/status/630201617300738048 <thats it

Comment: @JonPreece Excellent! Thank you so much, that's very promising.

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug yeah, definitely makes sense. Ryan's answer is good.

Comment: Another [unofficial styleguide](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/styleguide/styleguide.html) from @basarat

Comment: FWIW I am the maintainer of https://github.com/Platypi/style_typescript. I am updating it, and would love contributions if people feel there are things we need to cover!

Comment: Yet another useful and highly upvoted question with helpful answers. But of course we cannot have such kind of thing here so it's closed as off-topic. Great job, mods!

Comment: And there is Google's TS style guide: https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The TypeScript team doesn't issue an "official" style guide for other projects using TypeScript. The guidelines for working on the compiler itself are both too specific and not broad enough for general use; I would not use them as a baseline.

Any JavaScript style guide that is up-to-date for ES6 is going to cover nearly all TypeScript constructs except for type annotations, so I would start with your favorite JS style and decide on what you want the rules for type annotations to be.

[TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) is a good choice for enforcing style rules around types / type annotations.

**Update**: TSLint is currently deprectated in favour of [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint).

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this is a bit late, but I stumbled upon https://github.com/excelmicro/typescript which also provides a bit more detailed tslint.json in the linters folder ... it is also based on the airbnb/javascript styleguide ...

Yet another Styleguide (which we use for angular 1 development with TypeScript) is https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: The angular.io/styleguild link is broken.  Not sure why.

Comment: fixed the link. There is also an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17542

Comment: Adding mine too: https://github.com/unional/typescript-guidelines